# Adjacent columns matching two columns R

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame which looks something like this:

```
V1   V2   V3    V4   V5
A    C    B     D    NA
B    D    NA    NA   NA
D    B    A     E    NA 
D    A    C     E    B
```

and another data frame with paired columns such that:

```
Col1    Col2
  A      B
  B      D 
  C      E 
  B      A
  E      B
```

I want to use the paired data frame, containing Col1 and Col2, to find these consecutive pairs in the first data frame and the position of this.

So it'd result in something similar to:

```
[1]  3  4
[2]  1  2 
[3]  2  3 
[4]  3  4  5
```

I tried with for loops but it is extremely inefficient and error prone. I'd really appreciate some suggestion, maybe with apply function.

Comment: Why is the first result 3,4?

Comment: @NelsonGon because on the second data frame, second row (B D), matches with first row V3 and V4 from the first data frame. Two consecutive columns that match with those from the other df

Comment: What if you have multiple matches per row? For example, a row which contains `c("A", "B", "D")`? Also, please use `dput` to give us a working example (e.g. `dput(df1)`).

Comment: @January that's exactly what happens on the 4th row of the data frame. Then it'd give the position of the 3 matches

Comment: OK, but why are you producing only three numbers, and not `[4] 3 4 4 5`?

Comment: @January Well that would also be fine actually!

Comment: Are the values always single letters? Because in that case I would turn it to string matching exercise. Or are they numbers? Or what, actually?

Comment: @January well actually they are codes of a letter and 2 numbers such that: "A10", "B34", "C53" etc

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions, none of which is perfect. In the following, `df1` is  the first data frame, `df2` is the second data frame.

The following solution is based on the fact that the values are regular – always of the same format, and that they do not contain '--'.

```
df1B <- sapply(1:(ncol(df1) - 1), function(i) paste0(df1[,i], "--", df1[,i+1]))
pat <- paste0(df2[,1], "--", df2[,2])
apply(df1B, 1, function(r) which(r %in% pat))
```

This returns a list with one element in for each row. Given that your second number is always the first number plus one, the solution is equivalent to your expected result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 3 4
```

Note that this is not a general solution, because if one cell of df2 contained "A--B", then the search pattern would be for example "A--B--C" and would match both ("A--B", "C") and ("A", "B--C").

Converting the resulting list to a data frame format is possible, but tedious.

```
res <- apply(df1B, 1, function(r) which(r %in% pat))
max <- max(sapply(res, length))

df <- lapply(1:max, function(i) sapply(res, function(r) c(r[i], r[i] +1)))
df <- Reduce(cbind, lapply(df, t))
```

Result

```
> df
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4   NA   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA
[3,]    2    3   NA   NA
[4,]    3    4    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `apply` row-wise could be to create combination of row elements and `paste` them together, check how many of them occur together in pasted version of `df2` and return the indices.

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
    inds <- which(paste(x[-length(x)], x[-1]) %in% paste(df2$Col1, df2$Col2))
    unique(c(inds, inds + 1))
})

#[[1]]
#[1] 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 3 4 5
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "D"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("D", "E"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "B", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names 
= c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "E"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "D", "E"), class = "factor")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```